# Identity increment was jumping in sql server database ( Amazon server)

Tags: sql-server-2012, amazon-rds

I am using Sql server 2012(Amazon RDS). I have a table which has an identity column in it.At the beginning Identity column starts from 1,2 and so on and adding identity smoothly, but suddenly it jumps from  17018 to 27011.  What could be the reason. Please assist.

thanks,
Sella

Comment: Is anything else using that table?  Was a record inserted with an explicit ID at some point?

Comment: The identity is not guaranteed to increment by 1.

Comment: Did you delete some rows from that table at any point?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting server instance may cause this.
See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/668042/SQL-Server-Auto-Identity-Column-Value-Jump-Is)

Answer (score 0):

Any of these things can cause a jump in the identity column:

1. An insert into the table that is later rolled back
2. An error when inserting into the table (like unique constraint violation)
3. A delete from the table
4. Someone use `IDENTITY INSERT ON` to set a value for the identity column. If that value is bigger than the current value, the sequence will resume at that.
5. A server restart

In general, you shouldn't expect identity columns to increment by 1. Treat the value as random. The only difference between identity and a true random is that it's guaranteed to be increasing in value.